# How to get rows of matrix without using any loops in numpy or tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, array-broadcasting

I have a matrix and I want to read in each row of the matrix and use tf.nn.top_k to find the top k values for each row.

How would I get each row of the matrix without using loops or list comprehension. I want to use Tensorflow or numpy and I was thinking of applying broadcasting.

If I put the indices in an array, for example if there were 10 rows in the matrix, I would have:

```
indices = [0,1,2,3......,9]
```

and then I could apply broadcasting?

Comment: Tell us about `tf.nn.top_k`?  Does it only accept a 1d array (that is only one row of a 2d array)?  Broadcasting and/or indexing isn't going get around that kind of problem.

Comment: What is an example input and output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say (like in one other answer here):

`a = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (4,4))`

then you can simply do:

`np.sort(a)[:,-1:-3:-1]`

where instead of the `3` index you put a number related to how many top values you want to get.

**EDIT**:
In order to address your comment:
First, I change to float datatype (to deal with the 1/3 value):

`a = 1000*np.random.random((4,4))`

then I get the indexes:

`idx = a.argsort().argsort()`

assign 1/3 to top two values:

`a[idx>=2] = 1./3.`

and assign zero to rest:

`a[idx<2] = 0`

et voila.

Comment: after getting the top values, how can I change them to equal 1/3 and to set the rest of the values to be 0?

Comment: Thank you, this definitely helps. Is there still a way to do it with tf.nn.top_k or other tensorflow functions since I am trying to learn more about tensorflow

Comment: also what does a.argsort().argsort() do? why do we apply it twice?

Comment: It's pretty interesting and educative to follow what the `argsort().argsort()` does, thus I don't want to take the fun away from you. Take a look at the documentation and follow it on an easy one dimensional example. 
And sorry, I am not familiar with tensorflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this a number of different ways. The following way uses numpy's [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html).

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (4, 4))
a
```

returns

```
array([[712, 654, 871, 934],
       [639, 587, 216, 952],
       [853, 311, 598, 222],
       [466, 957, 306, 359]])
```

Then we can get the descending order of the arguments and use those to extract the corresponding elements:

```
o = np.argsort(a)[:, ::-1]
a[np.arange(4)[:, None], o[:, :2]]
```

returns

```
array([[934, 871],
       [952, 639],
       [853, 598],
       [957, 466]])
```

Comment: can I use this returned matrix to index my original matrix (i.e. broadcasting?)

Comment: That's what the variable `o` is... the x-indices (axis-1) for the original matrix.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [`tf.nn.top_k`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/top_k)

> Finds values and indices of the k largest entries for the last
>   dimension.

So, you can directly pass your tensor to this function and it will find the `k largest` elements from the last dimension. No need to use loops.

Comment: Yes when I pass in a matrix it finds the k largest in each row. However, what I want to do once I find these k largest is to replace them with 1/k and the rest of the elements in the row with zeros. How would I do that if it returns a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tensorflow way to do this.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output org drawer
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

mat = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (4, 4))
print(mat)

# All tensorflow from here
tmat = tf.convert_to_tensor(mat)

k = 3

# ki are the indices within each row
kv, ki = tf.nn.top_k(tmat, k)
kmin = tf.reduce_min(kv, axis=1)[:, None]

newmat = tf.where(tmat < kmin, tf.zeros_like(tmat, dtype=tf.float64), tf.ones_like(tmat) / k)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(newmat.eval())
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
:RESULTS:
[[ 97 805   0 104]
 [920 340 905  24]
 [439 243 705 161]
 [146 650 542 284]]
[[0.33333333 0.33333333 0.         0.33333333]
 [0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333 0.        ]
 [0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333 0.        ]
 [0.         0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333]]
:END:
```